# Button hover in sync with a highlighting of an image

Tags: css, image, hover, highlight

Is it possible to have a hover animation on a button that’s in-sync with highlighting the image?
Kind of like this website where if you hover over the button, it highlights the area of an image? (The yellow highlight on Canada)

Anyone know the CSS code behind this hover effect?

Image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0O3QN.jpg

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, i don't know the source code behind this hover effecr thus asking for help.